# testing in Paypal API vs. Stripe API?

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-sandbox, stripe-payments

Can anyone discuss some of the pros / cons / ease of use for Stripe's test mode vs. Paypal's sandbox testing? Specifics appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from personal experience, unless you need to accept PayPal payments, Stripe is way better than PayPal.

- PayPal is way too big to really care about small developers. Just look at the number of questions that actually gets answered. In general, whenever I'm faced with a PayPal-related problem, I can expect to solve this on my own rather than asking anyone from PayPal
- PayPal still need to support code from 10+ years ago that uses legacy SOAP stuff and meanwhile it also tries to come up with newer APIs. This just creates crazy amount of confusion. I might be exaggerating here but there are at least 5 ways to send a payment in PayPal, and 10 ways to receive a payment. With Stripe, it is just one API and that's all

These two are the main thing that discourages me from PayPal. There are tons of other issues like mystic error codes, slow website and weird restrictions here and there

If you can, just avoid PayPal integration and save yourself hours of pain and headache